# Prove or disprove: $S_{20}$ has an element of order 80.

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, symmetric-groups

To be frank I don't even have a clue where to start.

I know $80$ divides $20!$, so assuming with contradiction that exists such a $g \in S_{20}$ wouldn't derive a contradiction looking at $\langle g\rangle$.

I know Cauchy's theorem states its true if 80 was prime, but since it isn't I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Do you understand/know of any relationship between cycle structure and element order? For example, what is the order of $(12)(345)$ and why?

Comment: yes, i know two cycles are conjugated if they have the same cycle structures. I know how to calculate the order of an element in $S_n$ and determine if it's even or odd using the sign function. The order of your example would be the lcm(2,3) = 6.

Comment: OK great - what you need to do here is reverse-engineer the calculation to determine the order of an element of $S_n$. That is, if the order of an element is $80$ what must its cycle structure look like?

Comment: Well, it could either be a single 80 length cycle, which is not possible because we only have 20 elements. So I must check if exists a combination of numbers between 1 to 20 and check if their lcm might be 80?

Comment: Basically, yeah!

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot!

Comment: (p.s. by "I know $80 / 20!$..." , I guess you mean "I know $80$ divides $20!$..."?)

Comment: yes this is what i meant

Answer (score 5):

Sketchy answer: Find the prime decomposition of $80$, so $80=5\times 2^4$. As $5+16=21>20$, we see that $S_{20}$ contains no elements of order $80$ (but $S_{21}$ does).

Comment: Can you elaborate why this "smells" correctly? like why would this give you intuition if it's true or false?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question. Above you said you need to find "a combination of numbers between 1 to 20 and check if their lcm might be 80" - well, the optimal way of doing this is to take coprime numbers (as $\operatorname{lcm}(ax, ay)=\operatorname{lcm}(x, y)$), and $80$ has only 2 coprime factors.

Comment: I think i might be misunderstanding because based on what you wrote it means for all elements in $S_{20}$ we can find max lcm = 10. Is this the contradiction?

Comment: @MathStudent101 No; the numbers $2$ and $5$ come from the $80$ (claimed element order) rather than the $20$ in $S_{20}$. For example, $(1 \:2 \:3 \:4 \:5 \:6 \:7)$ has order $7$ and $(1\:2\:3\:4\:5\:6\:7)(8\:9\:10)$ has order $21$ (and lcm here is $21$).